# Portable program for connecting to Linux or Windows machine behind the same router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, remote-access, remote-control

I am searching for a program that will allow me to connect my computers in my home network behind a router in such a way that I can view, launch programs, see the results, browse the web on the other computer from another computer. This is possible in Team Viewer but since I am behind a router I think I do not need the internet connection. Is it possible to connect two computer without connecting to the net, if it is possible how can I do so? Does Team Viewer or a program of similar sort have support for this feature?

My main aim is to connect Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit with Windows 7 Professional 64-bit and Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit. Occasionally I will also connect Windows 7 Professional 64-bit to Ubuntu 12.04.5 32-bit LTS.

LAST EDIT: I think this is possible in Team Viewer I am trying to figure out how. I would be glad if someone provides assistance on the matter.

Comment: If all computers are all in the same room (next to each other) you can always use Synergy.. so using a single keyboard and mouse to control all 3 as if they are all part of 1 machine. You may want to ask TeamViewer support team if they can allow your TV instance to report back to a local server within your local network or not.

Comment: @Vesnothan  I find  [nomachine](https://www.nomachine.com/download) more efficient than temviewer. It is always a solution with a _server side_ (on who should share / receive commands) and a _client side_ (on those who want to use sharing and give commands remotely). As you can see the same program (server+client or only client) on the different OS. Direct connection (you need to give the IP), whole bandwidth, compressed if needed... End of __2019__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in Teamviewer using direct LAN connections.

On the teamviewer application window hit Extras then Options.  In the General tab under the heading 'Network Settings' you should see a setting called 'Incoming LAN connections' set this to accept or accept exclusively.  You need to set this on each machine that you want to receive LAN only connections.

Note that 'accept exclusively' will casue the machine to deny teamviewer access from outside the LAN so use with caution.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you want to connect.  An easy way would be to set up an ftp server on your GNU/Linux machine.  You could then simply ftp to it from the Windows machine and copy files as desired.

There are lots of ftp servers available for Linux which will depend on what disribution you have.  Simply search for ftpd in whatever package manager you happen to use.

http://proftpd.org/ is the site of one available in Fedora.

If your desire is to control the remote machine, that is also possible.  Search for remote desktops and you will find a variety of solutions.  If you are trying to control your Linux machine from windows.  All you need to do is forward your display from the Linux box to a program such as Xming.  See this other question for more details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453/what-is-a-good-and-free-x-server-for-windows

Linux controlling windows should also be possible but slightly more complicated.  I believe this may help but again, search for remote desktop.
http://www.rdesktop.org/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this is not exactly what I seek. I want to be able to send keystrokes, see the remote desktop, launch programs etc. I need the functionality of Team Viewer

Comment: That is a slightly different questions but still possible.  At least from Windows to Linux.  Both windows and Linux have remote desktop capabilities though imo it is more difficult to connect from Linux to operate a Windows machine than the other way around.  You should probably edit your question so that it indicates your desires.  You should also include the version of LInux and WIndows so that people can answer better.

Answer (score 1):

Something simliar like TeamViewer would be VNC (virtual network computing), e.g. tightvncserver. On ubuntu you can install it from the repositories and the Windows download can be found here: http://www.tightvnc.com/

On Windows you might have some problems, if you have not logged on the physical console, as the server is launched after you logged on.